# rails app doesnt parse csv file on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, nginx

Trying to parse a csv file to a rails db on a production on Ubuntu 13.10 (rails 4, ruby 2.1).

```
Processing by ProductsController#import as HTML
I, [2014-01-14T15:59:37.341149 #7542]  INFO -- :   
        Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",                
                     "authenticity_token"=>"f6LcqRW4YDKC6G49pdSjCzio4xqi2Kge+CgREqPAdGs=", 
                     "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000060f77a0 
                             @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140114-7542-1pqgays>, 
                             @original_filename="products.csv", @content_type="text/csv", 
                             @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"products.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">, 
                     "commit"=>"Upload", 
                     "category_id"=>"brus"}
I, [2014-01-14T15:59:37.438414 #7542]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://...
I, [2014-01-14T15:59:37.438616 #7542]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 97ms
                                                 (ActiveRecord: 41.3ms)
```

No results and the db does not change. But on development (os x) it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide the controller and model code for this process? It may be a strong parameters issue that's causing you some grief here.

Comment: It is probably not a strong parameters issue, if it is working on the local environment. It is more likely an issue with the file upload/configuration of the server. From what the log says, the file seems to be uploading successfuly, if you check that tmpfile in the server do you see the upload? Is there any way you can log part of the contents of the file to see if it is processing it correctly?

Comment: I check this problem in OS X in production mode and get the same issue. So csv file success parsed only in development env, but in production  parse doesnt work. Temp file is OK.

Comment: I have this exact same issue...and it seems to occur with tab-delimited excel text files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution for me was to check everyting that might be case sensitive. For example if you select all "*.**CSV**" files it won't work for files like "example.**csv**"